# UDP Multicast over different network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I am trying to send a simple message to different clients connected to local network/same router. But it is possible that the clients might be connected to different router and have different IP addresses, so I am using UDP broadcast group range 224.0.0.0 through 230.255.255.255 and a specific port number.
Currently, when I am in the same network I am able to send messages to these clients, but when they are connected to the different router, I am not able to send messages.
Am I doing it in a wrong way or should there be something which I am missing. I am trying to implement this in python.

Comment: The reason is one word: security. You don't want others to be able to flood your network if the know your public IP address.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing you can do in software to make this work. The routers that manage both the sending and receiving networks need to be configured to route and receive multicast traffic. This is not a trivial subject and will likely require advanced configuration of the [PIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Independent_Multicast) and [MBGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotocol_BGP) protocols in the routers and any firewalls that are present.